# Query Builder, where clause

Tags: query-builder

How to make in Query Builder (Doctrine) construction WHERE condition A AND (condition B OR condition C) ??

I have tried

```
->where
->andwhere
->orwhere
```

And

```
->where
->orwhere
->orwhere
```

But both dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
                ->where("bp.active = :active")
                ->andWhere("p.name1 Like :name OR p.name2 Like :name")
```